# Asymptotic estimation of a divergent integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, divergent-integrals

I am looking for an equivalent of the following integral : $$ \int_{0}^{A}{e^{t^\alpha}}dt  $$ with $0<\alpha$ when $A$ tends to infinity.

I call an equivalent a simpler function $f$ of $A$ such that $$ \int_{0}^{A}{e^{t^\alpha}}dt = f(A)(1 + o(1)) $$ when $A$ tends to infinity with the notation of Landau.

I have already tried an integration by part and a change of variable but I cannot control the last integral to show it is negligible.

If you have any idea. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By the L'Hospital rule
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{A \to  + \infty } \frac{{\int_0^A {e^{t^\alpha  } dt} }}{{\frac{1}{\alpha }A^{1 - \alpha } e^{A^\alpha  } }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{A \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{1 + \frac{{1 - \alpha }}{{\alpha A^\alpha  }}}} = 1,
$$
hence
$$
\int_0^A {e^{t^\alpha  } dt}  = \frac{1}{\alpha }A^{1 - \alpha } e^{A^\alpha  } (1 + o(1))
$$
as $A\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, that’s nice

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how do you find the function $\frac{1}{\alpha }A^{1 - \alpha } e^{A^\alpha  }$, is there any systematic method ?

Comment: I tried $f(A)e^{A^\alpha  }$ with an unknown $f$. Applied L'Hospital and assumed that $
f'(A)$ is negligible in comparison with $f(A)\alpha A^{\alpha  - 1}$. Finally I took the latter equal to $1$ and solved for $f$.

Comment: Ho that shows a good practice of asymptotics with integrals, have you any reference to study with ?

Comment: For this particular trick I do not have any references. For asymptotics of integrals in general, I can recommend Olver's "Asyptotics and Special Functions", Wong's "Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals", "Asymptotic Expansions of Integrals" by Handelsman and Bleistein, or Temme's "Asymptotic Methods for Integrals".

Comment: Thank you for help